# Android Camera2 how to set ISO sensitivity value after AE_MODE set AE_MODE_OFF automatically

Tags: android, iso, camera2

I'm using Camera2 API to modify Camera shutter speed.

So I have to set `CONTROL_AE_MODE` to `AE_MODE_OFF`.

Then auto-exposure algorithm will not override `SENSOR_SENSITIVITY` value.

But after shutter speed changed, sensitivity value become not suitable.
the preview become too dark or white.

My question is: How to change `SENSOR_SENSITIVITY` (ISO value) automatically when `AE_MODE` is `OFF`.

I know in iOS camera, they have `exposureTargetOffset` value to decide whether iso value suitable.

But I have not found in android camera2 api.

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

There's no semi-automatic mode in camera2 currently; if you turn off auto-exposure, you have to manually control both exposure and sensitivity.

You can leave AE on, and use [exposure compensation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CaptureRequest.html#CONTROL_AE_EXPOSURE_COMPENSATION) to darken/brighten the images instead.

Answer (score 2):

The `SENSOR_EXPOSURE_TIME` and `SENSOR_SENSITIVITY` can both be changed when AE Mode is off. The ranges of these settings may vary and can be requested by respectively `SENSOR_INFO_EXPOSURE_TIME_RANGE` and `SENSOR_INFO_SENSITIVITY_RANGE`.
Note that this is not possible on all phones!

You can take a look at the [Open Camera project](https://github.com/almalence/OpenCamera) as a great example for changing these values.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else wants an answer to this If you're using camera2 API in `CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback.onCaptureCompleted` you can get the current autoexposure time and iso sensitivity. This gets called for every preview frame. So you can run your preview with auto exposure on, and each time you get a preview frame save exposure multiplied by ISO

```
mExposureTimesISO=(double)(result.get(TotalCaptureResult.SENSOR_SENSITIVITY)*result.get(TotalCaptureResult.SENSOR_EXPOSURE_TIME));
```

Then in your picture taking call set it to manual exposure, then divide this value by your desired ISO, e.g. in my ISO 100 locked image capture routine it looks like the below:

```
double exposureAtISO100=mExposureTimesISO/100.0;            
CaptureRequest.Builder build=mCamera.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_STILL_CAPTURE);

build.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE,CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE_OFF);
build.set(CaptureRequest.SENSOR_SENSITIVITY,100);
build.set(CaptureRequest.SENSOR_EXPOSURE_TIME,(long)exposureAtISO100);
```